# How is location awareness on HDFS achieved when using Spark or Flink?

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, apache-flink

I'm wondering how the Spark or Flink execution engines (the master schedulers) find out the appropriate worker for each block.

The namenode will be capable of telling them the exact location of the block, but is this task done by the job managers of Spark and Flink, or is this something where YARN comes into play?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This was very helpful !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only tell for Flink. The `JobManager` requests the block information from `HDFS Namenode` and computes a block-task assignment. First, local blocks are assigned to each `TaskManger` (TM). If a TM does not have any local blocks, it gets remote blocks assigned. If no local blocks are available any more, all remaining blocks are assigned evenly over all TMs (to get good load balancing).